# Google Home - How to hook my own webservice URL

Tags: google-home, fulfillment

I would like to hook my own webservice running on my own system in webhook URL of the fullfilment ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with some qualifications. Your webhook must be at a publicly accessible address (you can't have the service available just to your local network) and it must handle HTTPS requests with a valid cert.